# Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. on Set Metadatanavigation

Tags: 2013

I am trying to add the navigation keys of one document library, however its failing on the Set Metadatanavigation Settings method with the above exception

```
var navigationKeyFilterxxxIsp =new MetadataNavigationKeyFilter(navigationFieldxxxIsp);
                                var navigationKeyFilterxxxITService =new MetadataNavigationKeyFilter(navigationFieldxxxITService);
                                var navigationKeyFilterxxxResponsible =new MetadataNavigationKeyFilter(navigationFieldxxxResponsible);
                                var navigationKeyFilterxxxStatus =new MetadataNavigationKeyFilter(navigationFieldxxxStatus);
                                var navigationKeyFilterxxxUpdateCycle =new MetadataNavigationKeyFilter(navigationFieldxxxUpdateCycle);
                                var navigationKeyFilterxxxClassification =new MetadataNavigationKeyFilter(navigationFieldxxxClassification);
                                var navigationKeyFilterxxxItowner = new MetadataNavigationKeyFilter(navigationFieldxxxItowner);
                                var navigationKeyFilterxxxBusinessOwner = new MetadataNavigationKeyFilter(navigationFieldxxxBusinessOwner);
                                var navigationKeyFilterxxxBusinessAudience = new MetadataNavigationKeyFilter(navigationFieldxxxBusinessAudience);

                                navigationSettings.AddConfiguredKeyFilter(navigationKeyFilterxxxIsp);
                                navigationSettings.AddConfiguredKeyFilter(navigationKeyFilterxxxITService);
                                navigationSettings.AddConfiguredKeyFilter(navigationKeyFilterxxxResponsible);
                                navigationSettings.AddConfiguredKeyFilter(navigationKeyFilterxxxStatus);
                                navigationSettings.AddConfiguredKeyFilter(navigationKeyFilterxxxUpdateCycle);
                                navigationSettings.AddConfiguredKeyFilter(navigationKeyFilterxxxClassification);
                                navigationSettings.AddConfiguredKeyFilter(navigationKeyFilterxxxItowner);
                                navigationSettings.AddConfiguredKeyFilter(navigationKeyFilterxxxBusinessOwner);
                                navigationSettings.AddConfiguredKeyFilter(navigationKeyFilterxxxBusinessAudience);

                                MetadataNavigationSettings.SetMetadataNavigationSettings(xxxDocumentLibrary,
                                                                                         navigationSettings, true);
                                xxxDocumentLibrary.Update();
                                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

                                #endregion


                                LoggingServiceTomDocumentationTrack.LogInfo(
                                    LoggingCategoryTomDocumentationTrack.Feature,
                                    String.Format("List with name '{0}' and url '{1}' created.", listName, listUrl));
                            }
                            catch (Exception exception)
                            {
                            }
```

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. on Set Metadatanavigation
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldIndexCollection.Add(SPField
>   primaryField, SPField secondaryField)
>              at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataNavigationSettings.ExecuteIndexingChanges(SPList
>   currentList, FieldIndexDictionary availableIndices,
>   FieldIndexDictionary indicesToDelete)
>              at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataNavigationSettings.UpdateMetadataNavigationIndexes(SPList
>   sourceList)
>              at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataNavigationSettings.SetMetadataNavigationSettings(SPList
>   sourceList, MetadataNavigationSettings listNavSettings, Boolean
>   updateListIndexing, Boolean requiresListUpdate)
>              at xxx.SP.IctDocumentation.Features.xxxIctDocumentationSiteLibrary.xxxIctDocumentationSiteLibraryEventReceiver.<>c_*DisplayClass3.b*_0()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Add this line to your code, this should clear any previously configured filters.

```
MetadataNavigationSettings.ClearConfiguredKeyFilters()
```

2) How many indexes do you have configured on the library. Navigate to List Settings -> and click on Indexed Columns. Remove any references to the above mentioned columns (or clear everything) and rerun the code. Or just specify false for list indexing.

```
MetadataNavigationSettings.SetMetadataNavigationSettings(xxxDocumentLibrary,                navigationSettings, false);
```